# Sharing a folder as hidden in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, home-networking, file-sharing, homegroup

I have a Windows 7 Homegroup with 4 computers. I share files among all of these. However, I want to have a folder on computer #1 that can only be seen and accessed by computer #2 and not by computers #3 and #4.

In Windows XP I think there was a trick with a $ sign in the shared path (mounting as $folderName instead of folderName), so that particular folder could only be manually linked directly from the destination machine and was not visible when exploring the network places. Can something similar be done in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` trick should work if you put it at the end (e.g. `share$`).

**Note** This only works in Windows. Linux machines will see the share anyway.